# Oracle Cloud: "channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused"

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Why every time have same problem to connect on cloud oracle
I am using TigerVNC

Can you help me?

PS C:\Users\maikc> ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 opc@132.226.245.54
Last login: Tue Aug 17 14:33:39 2021 from 187.182.215.101
[opc@java-basics-vm ~]$ **channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused**

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

Access server on terminal

```
PS C:\Users\maikc> ssh user@server
```

Show all server sessions

```
[opc@java-basics-vm ~]$ vncserver -list

[opc@java-basics-vm ~]$ vncserver -kill :(?) - Number of session
```

remove all folders other sessios

```
[opc@java-basics-vm ~]$ sudo rm /tmp/.X11-unix/X(?) - Number of session
```

now start new VNCserver

```
[opc@java-basics-vm ~]$ vncserver
```

Set new password VNCserver

```
[opc@java-basics-vm ~]$ vncpasswd
```

Logout/exit

```
[opc@java-basics-vm ~]$exit
```

Connect to server on terminal

```
PS C:\Users\maikc> ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 user@server
```